# How can I pass REST query parameters as optional in Oracle Application Express Listener?

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex

In Oracle Application Express Listener, we can create REST endpoints with a URI, lets say `users?limit={limit}` where limit it the maximum number of rows to fetch.

The problem is that if we specify a URI like that and try to access just `users` expecting to get all users, I receive a 404 error because the server can't find that URI.

The question is, is it possible to have these query parameters as optional?

I don't know what version of Apex we have, it looks like this:
[image]

One idea I had of to solve this, is a hack it's follow: Declare the URI as `users{params}`, where `params` would be all parameters and then parse the parameters in PL/SQL, this would work but very hacky indeed.

Comment: By definition every parameter wrote like `schem://URL/URI?param=value` are optional AND not part of the URI.

Comment: Hi @Zorglube does your system works like this, with those as optional on Apex? Can you tell me which version are you using and if there's some sort of configuration to make it behave like that? I'm asking because as I said, in the system I'm currently working with those are mandatory, without the parameter I get a 404 error.

Comment: I don't use Apex.

Comment: I just say, if Apex don't implement the usual habit and web standards... Sorry for you.

Comment: @Zorglube If you don't use Apex and gave a downvote can you please undo it, this question is really an issue for me that I would like to have solved, thank you!

Comment: I downvoted, because I didn't clearly unterstood your question, and I thought their is few misunterstanding at the origin of you question. (If you edit you question, StackOverflow will unlock me and I'll be able to remove my downvote).

Comment: @Zorglube I updated the question.

Comment: By the way your `hack` idea, seems very weird and dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly define the query parameters in the URL. You can just reference them as bind variables in the source.

For example, if i have a GET resource for employees table

../example/employees

the source of the resource can be

```
select * from emp where mgr = :mgr or :mgr is null
```

If I call **../example/employees** all employees will be returned (mgr is null)

but if I call **../example/employees?mgr=7839** only the employees with the manager 7839 will be returned.

I can also call **../example/employees?mgr=7839&limit=2** and the results will be limited to 2.

Check out this link for Jeff which has a good example

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/03/a-tale-of-two-styles-of-uris-and-parameters-words/